# create hidden input with thymeleaf data

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

So basically I have this table in my html page and its almost work as it should

```
<div th:each="good : ${goodList}">
<form action="#" th:action="@{/zamow}"
th:object="${enterGoodAction}" method="post">
    <tr>
   <input type="hidden" path="id" value="${good.id}"/> //this input
   <th><span th:text="${good.name}"/></th>
   <th><span th:text="${good.amount}"/></th>
   <th><span th:text="${good.price}" /></th>
   <th><span th:text="${good.tax}" /></th>
   <th><input type="number" min="1" th:field="*{amount}"/></th>
   <th><input type="submit" value="Zamów" /></th>
   </tr>

</form>
```

Now what I want to do is create this hidden input which will pass me "good.id" data to my controller but whatever i do with him he is always null. How can i fix it? I think controller works well so the problem is with my input only. Actual imput might looks silly but its my 10th try or something and I was desperate ;/

Answer (score 6):

The way you need to do to access an internal property of the object in the form is this

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{good.id}" />
```

I am assuming that you have an object with this structure

```
enterGoodAction.good.id
```

If is not the case find the right path from enterGoodAction object to the ID

Answer (score 0):

You just used `value`, which is a boring attribute and gets passed as-is. Use `th:value` (or `data-th-value`) instead.

Comment: Also tried with th:value there <input type="hidden" path="name" th:value="${good.id}"/> still null ;/

Comment: @Vesspe Then you're not clearly describing the results. You say "null", but an attribute can't be null (at least in the HTML). It can be non-present, it can be empty, it can be invalid. Show the rendered HTML.

Comment: @Vesspe If you're saying that *it's not submitted*, then that's because the `input` has no `name`...

Comment: By null I mean what my controller see where should be data from this input. Need to read about rendered html becouse I never heard of this.

Comment: @Vesspe Rendering HTML is the entire point of Thymeleaf. You need to understand how that works.

Comment: All my knowledge about it comes from http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html . And I don't see there any explanation what is exactly html rendering? Also I have to finish it for tomorrow, yes I know its not polite to ask someone to do my job but im absolutely out of ideas how to fix it.

Comment: @Vesspe "Rendering" means turning your Thymeleaf template into the HTML output. Use "view source" in your browser. Most likely, *it's that you don't have a name on the input*, like I said above. You need to learn about core Web debugging tools like source view and the Network console on your browser console.

Comment: So i set this to <input type="hidden" th:value="${good.name}" name="name" data-th-field="*{name}"/> and html on site says that my value is empty which is kinda weird becouse the table show data fine.
 <input name="name" value="" id="name" type="hidden">.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I had this weird problem where I was unable to set the "value" attribute of the `<input type="hidden">` field in thymeleaf. What worked for me which will probably be considered a jQuery hack though is

`<input id = "good-id" type="hidden"/>`

on the thymeleaf side

```
<script th:inline="javascript">   
       $(document).ready(function() {
       var goodIdValue = /*[[${good.id}]]*/'null';
       $("#good-id").val(goodIdValue);
       });
</script>
```

This sets the type `value` attribute of the hidden field using jQuery